# Finding the side lengths of a square given certain conditions involving interior measurements.

Tags: geometry

In the figure below, ABCD is a square. Find the length of AB.

[image]

I have been trying forever to figure out this problem, but I seem to get stuck after applying Pythagoras theorem on the two right-angled triangles. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Can you be more specific about what you have done so far please?  There aren't any right-angled triangles in the picture, so I don't know how to interpret your statement.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Pictorial solution]

My solution involves use of similar triangles, pythogoras theorem and a bit of constructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know analytic geometric, it will be easy for you to solve this problem. Just put the origin of cartesian axes in one of these interior right angle vertices.

Then, for instance, if you put the y-axis passing through C, C has coordinates $(0,6)$ and A will have coordinates $(1,-3)$. Using the distance formula you get

$${AC}^2=(1-0)^2+(-3-6)^2=1+81=82$$

And as $AC=AB\sqrt 2$, $$AB=\sqrt {41}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can just use the Pythagorean theorem:
[image]